# Error Messages for Django Login are not appearing?

Tags: html, django

I am building a web application that Django with a custom login field, and I want to include error messages if the user does not exist or uses the wrong password. I've tried a bunch of different approaches and looked at other SO questions, but no matter what, the error messages are not appearing on my page, and I am not sure what else to try.

For reference:

Login View:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            username = User.objects.get(email = email.lower()).username
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None :
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid email or password.")
                return render(request, 'registration/login.html', context = {'form': form})
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid email or password.")
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', context = {'form': form})

    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form' : form})
```

login.html:

```
{% if messages %}
      <ul class="messages" style="position: fixed; top: 40%; left: 78%; z-index: 100;">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
      </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Remove all the styling and html and check if messages is being print there or not? If messages is not going there then check if middleware is properly configured or not?

Comment: Hi Kaushal, thank you for your comment, removing the styling made it appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comments as an answer here as it solved the problem.

The Login view looks correct. Remove all the styling and html and check if messages is being print there or not? If messages is not going there then check if middleware is properly configured or not?

```
{% if messages %}
      <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
      </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @eballen1 You need to check the style you have given to your error message. z-index property:100  does not  seems right .
This property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
Also check if you have following things at place

```
#INSTALLED_APPS
django.contrib.messages
```

```py
#MIDDLEWARE or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in older versions:
django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware
django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
```

```py
#TEMPLATES
context_processors
django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages
```

Hope You find it helpful

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I double checked my settings and everything was set up correctly, I think I just had too much styling in the HTML file.

Comment: yes you got it right . You need to review your styles.